# d3.js canvas performance

Tags: javascript, canvas, physics, d3.js, svg

I've just rewritten [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/zpenoyre/Lt0euym5/8/) (a simple gravitational restricted n-body simulation) to display using canvas, rather than SVG. The reason being that I'd like to be able to run it with many thousands of particles.

To my surprise I didn't see any sizable performance improvement after making the conversion. I'm wondering if I've missed some simple step in the implementation, or if I'm misidentifying the bottleneck?

```
    var width=0.5*window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var height=width;
//var svg=d3.select("#sim").append("svg");
//svg.attr('width',width)
//  .attr('height',height);

var canvas = d3.select('#sim').append('canvas').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
var context = canvas.node().getContext('2d');

// instead of using svg and storing data in DOM we create a pseudo-DOM (maybe - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/d3-and-canvas-in-3-steps-8505c8b27444/)
//var customBase = document.createElement('custom');
//var custom = d3.select(customBase); // This is your SVG replacement and the parent of all other elements

var custom = d3.select('#sim').append('custom');

function databind(data) {
  var circles = custom.selectAll('custom.circle')
    .data(data);
  var enterSel = circles.enter()
    .append('custom').attr('class', 'circle')
    .attr('id',function(d) { return "particle" + d.id; })
    .attr('r',function(d) { return d.r; })
    .attr('cx', function(d) {return width*(d.x[0]+boxSize)/(2*boxSize);})
    .attr('cy', function(d) {return width*(d.x[1]+boxSize)/(2*boxSize);})
    .attr('fillStyle', function(d) {return d.c});
  circles.merge(enterSel)
    .transition()
    .attr('cx', function(d) {return width*(d.x[0]+boxSize)/(2*boxSize);})
    .attr('cy', function(d) {return width*(d.x[1]+boxSize)/(2*boxSize);})
    .attr('fillStyle', function(d) {return d.c});
}
//var join = custom.selectAll('custom.circle')  .data(data);
function draw(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  var elements = custom.selectAll('custom.circle');
  elements.each(function(d,i) {
    var node = d3.select(this);
    //console.log(node.attr('fillStyle'))
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(node.attr('cx'), node.attr('cy'), node.attr('r'), 0, 2*Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = node.attr('fillStyle');
    context.fill();
    //context.lineWidth = 1;
    //context.stroke();
  })
}

var info = d3.select('body').append('div')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('top', '0')
  .style('left', '0')
  .style('padding', '5px')
  .style('background-color', '#aaa');
var start = d3.now(), t0 = 0, sum = 0, cnt = 0;
var fmt = d3.format(",d");

var G=6.67e-11; // in SI
var mSun=2e30;
var kpc=3e19;
var Gyr=3.15e16;
var Galt=G*(mSun*(Gyr**2))/(kpc**3);

var rHat=[0,0,0];
var a1=[0,0,0];
var a2=[0,0,0];

function gravParticle(){
  this.id=0;
  this.m=1e6;
  this.x=[0,0,0];
  this.v=[0,0,0];
  this.a=[0,0,0];
  this.flag=0;
  this.c='black';
  this.r=2;
  this.smooth=0.1;
}
function gravity(p1,p2){ // calculating and updating the acceleration of a pair of particles
  var r=Math.sqrt((p2.x[0]-p1.x[0])**2 + (p2.x[1]-p1.x[1])**2 + (p2.x[2]-p1.x[2])**2 + p1.smooth**2 + p2.smooth**2);

  rHat[0]=(p2.x[0]-p1.x[0])/r;
  rHat[1]=(p2.x[1]-p1.x[1])/r;
  rHat[2]=(p2.x[2]-p1.x[2])/r;

  a1[0]=rHat[0]*Galt*p2.m/(r**2);
  a1[1]=rHat[1]*Galt*p2.m/(r**2);
  a1[2]=rHat[2]*Galt*p2.m/(r**2);

  a2[0]=-rHat[0]*Galt*p1.m/(r**2);
  a2[1]=-rHat[1]*Galt*p1.m/(r**2);
  a2[2]=-rHat[2]*Galt*p1.m/(r**2);

  p1.a[0]=p1.a[0]+a1[0];
  p1.a[1]=p1.a[1]+a1[1];
  p1.a[2]=p1.a[2]+a1[2];

  p2.a[0]=p2.a[0]+a2[0];
  p2.a[1]=p2.a[1]+a2[1];
  p2.a[2]=p2.a[2]+a2[2];
}
function update(ps){
  clearAcc(ps)
  for (var i=0; i<nParticles; i++){
    if (ps[i].flag == 1){
      var index=ps[i].id;
      for (var j=i+1; j<nParticles; j++){
        gravity(ps[i],ps[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
var boxSize=30;
var ps=[];
var host = new gravParticle();
host.m=1e11;
host.flag=1;
host.c='red';
host.r=20;
host.smooth=1;
var sat = new gravParticle();
sat.m=1e10;
sat.id=1;
sat.flag=1;
sat.x=[20,0,0];
sat.v=[0,-200,0];
sat.r=10;
sat.c='blue';
sat.smooth=0.5;
host.v[1]=-(sat.m/host.m)*sat.v[1];
ps.push(host);
ps.push(sat);
rMin=1;
rMax=20;
var nPassive=100;
for (var i=0;i<nPassive;i++){
  var pNew = new gravParticle();
  pNew.m=1e11/nPassive;
  pNew.id=i+2;
  pNew.flag=0;
  var theta=Math.PI*Math.random();
  var phi=2*Math.PI*Math.random();
  var r=rMin+Math.random()*(rMax - rMin);
  pNew.x=[r*Math.cos(phi)*Math.sin(theta),r*Math.sin(phi)*Math.sin(theta),r*Math.cos(theta)];

  var vTheta=Math.PI*Math.random();
  var vPhi=2*Math.PI*Math.random();
  var v=Math.sqrt(Galt*1e11/r);
  pNew.v=[v*Math.cos(vPhi)*Math.sin(vTheta),v*Math.sin(vPhi)*Math.sin(vTheta),v*Math.cos(vTheta)];
  //pNew.v=[150*randn_bm(),150*randn_bm(),150*randn_bm()];
  pNew.smooth=0.1;
  ps.push(pNew);
}

var nParticles=ps.length;

//var circles=custom.selectAll(".node")
//  .data(ps)
//  .enter()
//  .append('circle')
//  .attr('id',function(d) { return "particle" + d.id; })
//  .attr('r',function(d) { return d.r; })
//  .style("fill", function(d) {return d.c})
//  .attr('cx', function(d) {return width*(d.x[0]+boxSize)/(2*boxSize);})
//  .attr('cy', function(d) {return width*(d.x[1]+boxSize)/(2*boxSize);});


var dt=0.001;

update(ps);
databind(ps);
draw();

var t=0;

function evolve() {
  for (var i=0; i< nParticles; i++){
    ps[i].v[0]=ps[i].v[0]+ps[i].a[0]*dt/2;
    ps[i].v[1]=ps[i].v[1]+ps[i].a[1]*dt/2;
    ps[i].v[2]=ps[i].v[2]+ps[i].a[2]*dt/2;

    ps[i].x[0]=ps[i].x[0]+ps[i].v[0]*dt;
    ps[i].x[1]=ps[i].x[1]+ps[i].v[1]*dt;
    ps[i].x[2]=ps[i].x[2]+ps[i].v[2]*dt;
  }
  update(ps); // finds new acceleration
  for (var i=0; i < nParticles; i++){
    ps[i].v[0]=ps[i].v[0]+ps[i].a[0]*dt/2;
    ps[i].v[1]=ps[i].v[1]+ps[i].a[1]*dt/2;
    ps[i].v[2]=ps[i].v[2]+ps[i].a[2]*dt/2;
    //if (i>1000) {continue;}

    var thisCircle=d3.select('#particle'+ps[i].id);
    thisCircle
      .attr('cx', function(d) {return width*(d.x[0]+boxSize)/(2*boxSize);})
      .attr('cy',function(d) {return width*(d.x[1]+boxSize)/(2*boxSize);})
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.flag==0){ return d3.interpolateSpectral((d.x[2]+boxSize)/(2*boxSize))}
        return d.c
      })
  }
  draw();
  t = d3.now();
  var fps = 1000 / (t - t0);
  info.html(fmt(fps) + " fps = " + fmt(fps) + ' frames/sec');
  t0=t;
}

function clearAcc(ps){ // clearing old accelerations at each step
  for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
    ps[i].a=[0,0,0];
  }
}

var startStop=1
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 32){
      startStop=(startStop+1)%2
      if (startStop==0) {timer.stop();}
      if (startStop==1) {timer.restart(evolve,1000/60);}
  }
}
var timer=d3.interval(evolve,1000/60);

// Standard Normal variate using Box-Muller transform.
function randn_bm() {
  var u = 0, v = 0;
  while(u === 0) u = Math.random(); //Converting [0,1) to (0,1)
  while(v === 0) v = Math.random();
  return Math.sqrt( -2.0 * Math.log( u ) ) * Math.cos( 2.0 * Math.PI * v );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before anything else, the tutorial you're referencing is this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/d3-and-canvas-in-3-steps-8505c8b27444/

By reading the tutorial you'll see that the elements we'll create for manipulating the `<canvas>`...

> ... don’t live in the DOM but only in memory (in a ‘virtual’ DOM) and describe the life-cycle of these elements in a known D3 way.

However, this is what you did in your code:

```
var custom = d3.select('#sim').append('custom');
```

By doing that, you're **actually appending** a meaningless element called `<custom>` to the DOM! If you inspect your page you'll see thousands of them:

```
<div class="sim" id="sim">
    <canvas width="615" height="615"></canvas>
    <custom>
        <custom class="circle" id="particle0" r="20" cx="307.5" cy="307.5" fillstyle="red"></custom>
        <custom class="circle" id="particle1" r="10" cx="512.5" cy="307.5" fillstyle="blue"></custom>
        <custom class="circle" id="particle2" r="2" cx="313.23860812263854" cy="267.5420080575814" fillstyle="black"></custom>
        <custom class="circle" id="particle3" r="2" cx="210.56926409724912" cy="223.62781812619318" fillstyle="black"></custom>
        etc...
    </custom>
</div>
```

Because of that you're missing the whole point of using HTML canvas instead of SVG, and losing all its performance. In other words: you changed SVG for canvas but you're still appending and manipulating DOM elements, which is the very drawback of SVGs.

### Using D3 with HTML canvas

Just like the tutorial you mentioned in your question, create an element **without appending it**:

```
var customBase = document.createElement('custom');

var custom = d3.select(customBase);
```

That's, by far, the most important change here. But there are other needed changes as well:

You don't need to draw anything in your enter/update selection, therefore you don't need to set attributes to them. The important thing here is entering/updating the elements and binding data to them.

That being said, it can be just:

```
function databind(data) {
  var circles = custom.selectAll('custom')
    .data(data);
  var enterSel = circles.enter()
    .append('custom');
  circles = circles.merge(enterSel);
}
```

By the way, you're missing an exit selection here. I don't know if missed it on purpose or not.

Then, after simplifying your selections, use the datum in the `draw` function itself:

```
function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  custom.selectAll('custom').each(function(d, i) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(width * (d.x[0] + boxSize) / (2 * boxSize), width * (d.x[1] + boxSize) / (2 * boxSize), d.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = d.c;
    context.fill();
  })
}
```

With these changes we get a solid 30-35 fps, way better than your 13-14fps:

```js
var width = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var height = width;

var canvas = d3.select('#sim').append('canvas').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
var context = canvas.node().getContext('2d');

var customBase = document.createElement('custom');

var custom = d3.select(customBase);

function databind(data) {
  var circles = custom.selectAll('custom')
    .data(data);
  var enterSel = circles.enter()
    .append('custom');
  circles = circles.merge(enterSel);
}
//var join = custom.selectAll('custom.circle')  .data(data);
function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  custom.selectAll('custom').each(function(d, i) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(width * (d.x[0] + boxSize) / (2 * boxSize), width * (d.x[1] + boxSize) / (2 * boxSize), d.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = d.c;
    context.fill();
  })
}

var info = d3.select('body').append('div')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('top', '0')
  .style('left', '0')
  .style('padding', '5px')
  .style('background-color', '#aaa');
var start = d3.now(),
  t0 = 0,
  sum = 0,
  cnt = 0;
var fmt = d3.format(",d");

var G = 6.67e-11; // in SI
var mSun = 2e30;
var kpc = 3e19;
var Gyr = 3.15e16;
var Galt = G * (mSun * (Gyr ** 2)) / (kpc ** 3);

var rHat = [0, 0, 0];
var a1 = [0, 0, 0];
var a2 = [0, 0, 0];

function gravParticle() {
  this.id = 0;
  this.m = 1e6;
  this.x = [0, 0, 0];
  this.v = [0, 0, 0];
  this.a = [0, 0, 0];
  this.flag = 0;
  this.c = 'black';
  this.r = 2;
  this.smooth = 0.1;
}

function gravity(p1, p2) { // calculating and updating the acceleration of a pair of particles
  var r = Math.sqrt((p2.x[0] - p1.x[0]) ** 2 + (p2.x[1] - p1.x[1]) ** 2 + (p2.x[2] - p1.x[2]) ** 2 + p1.smooth ** 2 + p2.smooth ** 2);

  rHat[0] = (p2.x[0] - p1.x[0]) / r;
  rHat[1] = (p2.x[1] - p1.x[1]) / r;
  rHat[2] = (p2.x[2] - p1.x[2]) / r;

  a1[0] = rHat[0] * Galt * p2.m / (r ** 2);
  a1[1] = rHat[1] * Galt * p2.m / (r ** 2);
  a1[2] = rHat[2] * Galt * p2.m / (r ** 2);

  a2[0] = -rHat[0] * Galt * p1.m / (r ** 2);
  a2[1] = -rHat[1] * Galt * p1.m / (r ** 2);
  a2[2] = -rHat[2] * Galt * p1.m / (r ** 2);

  p1.a[0] = p1.a[0] + a1[0];
  p1.a[1] = p1.a[1] + a1[1];
  p1.a[2] = p1.a[2] + a1[2];

  p2.a[0] = p2.a[0] + a2[0];
  p2.a[1] = p2.a[1] + a2[1];
  p2.a[2] = p2.a[2] + a2[2];
}

function update(ps) {
  clearAcc(ps)
  for (var i = 0; i < nParticles; i++) {
    if (ps[i].flag == 1) {
      var index = ps[i].id;
      for (var j = i + 1; j < nParticles; j++) {
        gravity(ps[i], ps[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
var boxSize = 30;
var ps = [];
var host = new gravParticle();
host.m = 1e11;
host.flag = 1;
host.c = 'red';
host.r = 20;
host.smooth = 1;
var sat = new gravParticle();
sat.m = 1e10;
sat.id = 1;
sat.flag = 1;
sat.x = [20, 0, 0];
sat.v = [0, -200, 0];
sat.r = 10;
sat.c = 'blue';
sat.smooth = 0.5;
host.v[1] = -(sat.m / host.m) * sat.v[1];
ps.push(host);
ps.push(sat);
rMin = 1;
rMax = 20;
var nPassive = 5000;
for (var i = 0; i < nPassive; i++) {
  var pNew = new gravParticle();
  pNew.m = 1e11 / nPassive;
  pNew.id = i + 2;
  pNew.flag = 0;
  var theta = Math.PI * Math.random();
  var phi = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
  var r = rMin + Math.random() * (rMax - rMin);
  pNew.x = [r * Math.cos(phi) * Math.sin(theta), r * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta), r * Math.cos(theta)];

  var vTheta = Math.PI * Math.random();
  var vPhi = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
  var v = Math.sqrt(Galt * 1e11 / r);
  pNew.v = [v * Math.cos(vPhi) * Math.sin(vTheta), v * Math.sin(vPhi) * Math.sin(vTheta), v * Math.cos(vTheta)];
  //pNew.v=[150*randn_bm(),150*randn_bm(),150*randn_bm()];
  pNew.smooth = 0.1;
  ps.push(pNew);
}

var nParticles = ps.length;

var dt = 0.001;

update(ps);
databind(ps);
draw();

var t = 0;

function evolve() {
  for (var i = 0; i < nParticles; i++) {
    ps[i].v[0] = ps[i].v[0] + ps[i].a[0] * dt / 2;
    ps[i].v[1] = ps[i].v[1] + ps[i].a[1] * dt / 2;
    ps[i].v[2] = ps[i].v[2] + ps[i].a[2] * dt / 2;

    ps[i].x[0] = ps[i].x[0] + ps[i].v[0] * dt;
    ps[i].x[1] = ps[i].x[1] + ps[i].v[1] * dt;
    ps[i].x[2] = ps[i].x[2] + ps[i].v[2] * dt;
  }
  update(ps); // finds new acceleration
  for (var i = 0; i < nParticles; i++) {
    ps[i].v[0] = ps[i].v[0] + ps[i].a[0] * dt / 2;
    ps[i].v[1] = ps[i].v[1] + ps[i].a[1] * dt / 2;
    ps[i].v[2] = ps[i].v[2] + ps[i].a[2] * dt / 2;
    //if (i>1000) {continue;}

    var thisCircle = d3.select('#particle' + ps[i].id);
    thisCircle
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return width * (d.x[0] + boxSize) / (2 * boxSize);
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return width * (d.x[1] + boxSize) / (2 * boxSize);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d.c
      })
  }
  draw();
  t = d3.now();
  var fps = 1000 / (t - t0);
  info.html(fmt(fps) + " fps = " + fmt(fps) + ' frames/sec');
  t0 = t;
}

function clearAcc(ps) { // clearing old accelerations at each step
  for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
    ps[i].a = [0, 0, 0];
  }
}

var startStop = 1
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    startStop = (startStop + 1) % 2
    if (startStop == 0) {
      timer.stop();
    }
    if (startStop == 1) {
      timer.restart(evolve, 1000 / 60);
    }
  }
}
var timer = d3.interval(evolve, 1000 / 60);

// Standard Normal variate using Box-Muller transform.
function randn_bm() {
  var u = 0,
    v = 0;
  while (u === 0) u = Math.random(); //Converting [0,1) to (0,1)
  while (v === 0) v = Math.random();
  return Math.sqrt(-2.0 * Math.log(u)) * Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * v);
}
```

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  /* Magic begins */
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vw;
}

div.sim {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 50%;
}

div .link {
  stroke: #bbb;
}

.node circle {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  r: 2px
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.text {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: Futura, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

h1 {
  margin: 3%;
  font-size: 32px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 3%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

p {
  margin: 3%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sim" id="sim"> </div>
</div>
```

Bear in mind that this is just the beginning, there is room for lots of improvements (both D3 related and general JavaScript good practices, like using `let` and `const`). For instance, if you remove that ID selection inside `evolve` (whose purpose is not clear for me), we get something around **50 fps**:

```js
var width = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var height = width;

var canvas = d3.select('#sim').append('canvas').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
var context = canvas.node().getContext('2d');

var customBase = document.createElement('custom');

var custom = d3.select(customBase);

//var join = custom.selectAll('custom.circle')  .data(data);
function draw(data) {
  var circles = custom.selectAll('custom')
    .data(data);
  var enterSel = circles.enter()
    .append('custom');
  circles = circles.merge(enterSel);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  circles.each(function(d, i) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(width * (d.x[0] + boxSize) / (2 * boxSize), width * (d.x[1] + boxSize) / (2 * boxSize), d.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = d.c;
    context.fill();
  })
}

var info = d3.select('body').append('div')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('top', '0')
  .style('left', '0')
  .style('padding', '5px')
  .style('background-color', '#aaa');
var start = d3.now(),
  t0 = 0,
  sum = 0,
  cnt = 0;
var fmt = d3.format(",d");

var G = 6.67e-11; // in SI
var mSun = 2e30;
var kpc = 3e19;
var Gyr = 3.15e16;
var Galt = G * (mSun * (Gyr ** 2)) / (kpc ** 3);

var rHat = [0, 0, 0];
var a1 = [0, 0, 0];
var a2 = [0, 0, 0];

function gravParticle() {
  this.id = 0;
  this.m = 1e6;
  this.x = [0, 0, 0];
  this.v = [0, 0, 0];
  this.a = [0, 0, 0];
  this.flag = 0;
  this.c = 'black';
  this.r = 2;
  this.smooth = 0.1;
}

function gravity(p1, p2) { // calculating and updating the acceleration of a pair of particles
  var r = Math.sqrt((p2.x[0] - p1.x[0]) ** 2 + (p2.x[1] - p1.x[1]) ** 2 + (p2.x[2] - p1.x[2]) ** 2 + p1.smooth ** 2 + p2.smooth ** 2);

  rHat[0] = (p2.x[0] - p1.x[0]) / r;
  rHat[1] = (p2.x[1] - p1.x[1]) / r;
  rHat[2] = (p2.x[2] - p1.x[2]) / r;

  a1[0] = rHat[0] * Galt * p2.m / (r ** 2);
  a1[1] = rHat[1] * Galt * p2.m / (r ** 2);
  a1[2] = rHat[2] * Galt * p2.m / (r ** 2);

  a2[0] = -rHat[0] * Galt * p1.m / (r ** 2);
  a2[1] = -rHat[1] * Galt * p1.m / (r ** 2);
  a2[2] = -rHat[2] * Galt * p1.m / (r ** 2);

  p1.a[0] = p1.a[0] + a1[0];
  p1.a[1] = p1.a[1] + a1[1];
  p1.a[2] = p1.a[2] + a1[2];

  p2.a[0] = p2.a[0] + a2[0];
  p2.a[1] = p2.a[1] + a2[1];
  p2.a[2] = p2.a[2] + a2[2];
}

function update(ps) {
  clearAcc(ps)
  for (var i = 0; i < nParticles; i++) {
    if (ps[i].flag == 1) {
      var index = ps[i].id;
      for (var j = i + 1; j < nParticles; j++) {
        gravity(ps[i], ps[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
var boxSize = 30;
var ps = [];
var host = new gravParticle();
host.m = 1e11;
host.flag = 1;
host.c = 'red';
host.r = 20;
host.smooth = 1;
var sat = new gravParticle();
sat.m = 1e10;
sat.id = 1;
sat.flag = 1;
sat.x = [20, 0, 0];
sat.v = [0, -200, 0];
sat.r = 10;
sat.c = 'blue';
sat.smooth = 0.5;
host.v[1] = -(sat.m / host.m) * sat.v[1];
ps.push(host);
ps.push(sat);
rMin = 1;
rMax = 20;
var nPassive = 5000;
for (var i = 0; i < nPassive; i++) {
  var pNew = new gravParticle();
  pNew.m = 1e11 / nPassive;
  pNew.id = i + 2;
  pNew.flag = 0;
  var theta = Math.PI * Math.random();
  var phi = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
  var r = rMin + Math.random() * (rMax - rMin);
  pNew.x = [r * Math.cos(phi) * Math.sin(theta), r * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta), r * Math.cos(theta)];

  var vTheta = Math.PI * Math.random();
  var vPhi = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
  var v = Math.sqrt(Galt * 1e11 / r);
  pNew.v = [v * Math.cos(vPhi) * Math.sin(vTheta), v * Math.sin(vPhi) * Math.sin(vTheta), v * Math.cos(vTheta)];
  //pNew.v=[150*randn_bm(),150*randn_bm(),150*randn_bm()];
  pNew.smooth = 0.1;
  ps.push(pNew);
}

var nParticles = ps.length;

var dt = 0.001;

update(ps);
draw(ps);

var t = 0;

function evolve() {
  for (var i = 0; i < nParticles; i++) {
    ps[i].v[0] = ps[i].v[0] + ps[i].a[0] * dt / 2;
    ps[i].v[1] = ps[i].v[1] + ps[i].a[1] * dt / 2;
    ps[i].v[2] = ps[i].v[2] + ps[i].a[2] * dt / 2;

    ps[i].x[0] = ps[i].x[0] + ps[i].v[0] * dt;
    ps[i].x[1] = ps[i].x[1] + ps[i].v[1] * dt;
    ps[i].x[2] = ps[i].x[2] + ps[i].v[2] * dt;
  }
  update(ps); // finds new acceleration
  for (var i = 0; i < nParticles; i++) {
    ps[i].v[0] = ps[i].v[0] + ps[i].a[0] * dt / 2;
    ps[i].v[1] = ps[i].v[1] + ps[i].a[1] * dt / 2;
    ps[i].v[2] = ps[i].v[2] + ps[i].a[2] * dt / 2;
    //if (i>1000) {continue;}
  }
  draw(ps);
  t = d3.now();
  var fps = 1000 / (t - t0);
  info.html(fmt(fps) + " fps = " + fmt(fps) + ' frames/sec');
  t0 = t;
}

function clearAcc(ps) { // clearing old accelerations at each step
  for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
    ps[i].a = [0, 0, 0];
  }
}

var startStop = 1
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    startStop = (startStop + 1) % 2
    if (startStop == 0) {
      timer.stop();
    }
    if (startStop == 1) {
      timer.restart(evolve, 1000 / 60);
    }
  }
}
var timer = d3.interval(evolve, 1000 / 60);

// Standard Normal variate using Box-Muller transform.
function randn_bm() {
  var u = 0,
    v = 0;
  while (u === 0) u = Math.random(); //Converting [0,1) to (0,1)
  while (v === 0) v = Math.random();
  return Math.sqrt(-2.0 * Math.log(u)) * Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * v);
}
```

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  /* Magic begins */
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vw;
}

div.sim {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 50%;
}

div .link {
  stroke: #bbb;
}

.node circle {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  r: 2px
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.text {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: Futura, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

h1 {
  margin: 3%;
  font-size: 32px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 3%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

p {
  margin: 3%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sim" id="sim"> </div>
</div>
```